# C Input getch(), skip when nothing pressed like Snake (game)

Tags: c, input, header, dev-c++

I have to program a game in C in the console. For example I want to count something up when I press the space key. But only while I press the key. When I release the key again it should stop counting and start again when I press it again. I want it like snake, I mean it doesn't stop for the input it gets the input when the user pressed it.

I have tried with kbhit, it counts up and when I press something it prints nothing for ever, even if I press a key again.

```c
while (1) {
        h = kbhit();
        fflush(stdin);
        if (h) {

            printf("%d\n", a);
            a += 1;

        } else {
            printf("nothing\n");
        }

    }
```

I expect 
nothing
nothing
nothing
`presses a key`
0
nothing
`presses key again`
1
`hold on key`
2
3
4

Thanks

Comment: Just off the top of my head, I would fork the function.  One gets the user input and places into global variable.  The other fork does what is in the global variable and clears it.  If there is nothing in the global variable, then it does nothing.

Comment: Can you write me an example, I don't exactly understand what you mean

Comment: I don't write code, I modify it. So give it a try first.  Use fork.  Parent fork runs getch() in a loop waiting for `q` to quit, else it puts input into a global variable for the child.  The child fork runs the game normally if the gloabal variable is empty (no input).  If the global variable has input, move in that direction and clear the variable and run normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, you did not store the key pressed into a variable.
Please have a go with this method.

The first 3 lines shows how to store a keyboard hit variable into h.
The rest will be incrementing the a value.

```
while (1) {

    /* if keyboard hit, get char and store it to h */
    if(kbhit()){

        h = getch();
    }

    /*** 
        If you would like to control different directions, there are two ways to do this.
        You can do it with if or switch statement.
        Both of the examples are written below.
    ***/

    /* --- if statement version --- */
    if(h == 0){

        printf("%d\n", a);
        a += 1;
    }
    else{

        printf("nothing\n");
    }

    /* --- switch statement version --- */
    switch(h)
    {
        case 0:
            printf("%d\n", a);
            a += 1;
        break;

        default: printf("nothing\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard (and ***correct***) way to do this (with `<conio.h>` stuff) is:

```
int c;
while (1)
{
```

or:

```
int c;
bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
```

with a loop body something like:

```
  if (kbhit())
  {
    switch (c = getch())
    {
      case 0:
      case 0xE0:
        switch (c = getch())
        {
          /* process "extended" key codes */
        }
        break;

      /* process "normal" key codes */
      case ...:
        ...
    }
  }

  /* add timer delay here! */

}
```

Somewhere in there you should either set `delay = true` or `return` from the function, however you wish to set up your loop termination. (I typically recommend you have a function specifically for the loop body.)

You should have access to a function called either "delay" or "sleep" (`sleep()` is the Windows OS function) that will allow you to delay between loops, somewhere between 50 and 100 milliseconds is more than sufficient.

If you wish to be really sophisticated, you can track the amount of time that has passed since the last loop and delay appropriately. For a game like Snake, however, you can easily skip all that, just use a fixed delay value.

Now, for the question not asked: why are you messing with old `<conio.h>` stuff anyway? Get yourself a copy of SDL2 and go to town. Life will be easier and the results *much* more satisfying.